# I'm trying to create a simplified IF statement that only accepts numbers

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, terminal

Here is my current code

---

```
@echo off
IF "%~1"=="/?" goto :showhelp
set "137501arg="
set /a "137501arg=%~1"
set "137501arg2="
set /a "137501arg2=%~3"
IF "%137501arg%" LEQ "0" goto :validarguments
IF "%137501arg%" GEQ "0" goto :validarguments
:badarguments
Echo Error: Wrong data in arguments.
goto :eof
:validarguments
IF %137501arg2% LEQ 0 goto :validarguments1
IF %137501arg2% GEQ 0 goto :validarguments1
goto :badarguments
:validarguments1
IF "%~2"=="Return" goto :validargumentsreturn
IF "%~2"=="return" goto :validargumentsreturn
goto :badarguments
:validargumentsreturn
IF "%137501arg%"=="%137501arg2%" (
IF "%~4"=="(" (
set 137501argumentnumber=0
:validargumentsblock
set /a 137501argumentnumber=%137501argumentnumber% + 1
set /p 137501arg%137501argumentnumber%= More?
IF "%137501arg%"==")" goto :validargumentsparse
goto :validargumentsblock
:validargumentsparse
set 137501currentargument=0
:validargumentsparse1
set /a 137501currentargument=%137501currentargument% + 1
set 137501argument%137501currentargument%=%137501arg%%137501currentargument%
IF "%137501argument%137501currentargument%"==")" goto :validargumentsparse2
goto validargumentsparse1
:validargumentsparse2
set 137501currentargument1=0
:validargumentsparse3
set /a 137501currentargument1=%137501currentargument1% + 1
%137501argument%%137501currentargument1%
IF "%137501currentargument1%"=="%137501currentargument" goto :eof
)
%~4 %~5 %~6 %~7 %~8 %~9
goto :eof
)
goto :eof
:showhelp
Echo Usage: %~n0 varName Return Value Input
```

---

Using this command to use a single command when the first and third arguments originally worked, however when I added the :validargumentsblock part it no longer worked. Also when I'm trying to use a "(" instead of a command at the end gives me this error,

---

```
Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (-x11), or octal (021).
Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (-x11), or octal (021).
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

---

What I'm trying to do is let it function like a IF statement however only let it accept numbers. I am trying to make it work like

```
when Var Return 5 (
echo The var is equal to 5.
goto :eof
)
echo The var is not equal to 5.
```

---

I know that IF VAR EQU NUM is similar to this but it can be used with letters, I'm trying to prevent it from accepting any letters.

---

---

I did end up editing it and did what magoo said and now the only error I get is  ***the syntax of the command is incorrect*** 
My code now is

---

```
@echo off
IF "%~1"=="/?" goto :showhelp
    set "A137501arg="
    set /a "A137501arg=%~1"
    set "A137501arg2="
    set /a "A137501arg2=%~3"
IF "%A137501arg%" LEQ "0" goto :validarguments
IF "%A137501arg%" GEQ "0" goto :validarguments
:badarguments
Echo Error: Wrong data in arguments.
goto :eof
:validarguments
IF %A137501arg2% LEQ 0 goto :validarguments1
IF %A137501arg2% GEQ 0 goto :validarguments1
goto :badarguments
:validarguments1
IF "%~2"=="Return" goto :validargumentsreturn
IF "%~2"=="return" goto :validargumentsreturn
IF "%~2"=="Returns" goto :validargumentsreturn
IF "%~2"=="returns" goto :validargumentsreturn
goto :badarguments
:validargumentsreturn
IF "%A137501arg%"=="%A137501arg2%" (
IF "%~5"=="(" goto validargumentsblock
goto validargumentsend
:validargumentblock
set A137501argumentnumber=0
:validargumentsblock1
set /a A137501argumentnumber=%A137501argumentnumber% + 1
set /p A137501arg%A137501argumentnumber%= More?
IF "%A137501arg%"==")" goto :validargumentsparse
goto :validargumentsblock
:validargumentsparse
set A137501currentargument=0
:validargumentsparse1
set /a A137501currentargument=%A137501currentargument% + 1
set A137501argument%A137501currentargument%=%A137501arg%A137501currentargument%%
IF "%A137501argument%A137501currentargument%"==")" goto :validargumentsparse2
goto validargumentsparse1
:validargumentsparse2
set A137501currentargument1=0
:validargumentsparse3
set /a A137501currentargument1=%A137501currentargument1% + 1
%A137501argument%%A137501currentargument1%
IF "%A137501currentargument1%"=="%A137501currentargument" goto :eof
goto :eof
:validargumentsend
%~4 %~5 %~6 %~7 %~8 %~9
goto :eof
)
goto :eof
:showhelp
Echo Usage: %~n0 varName Return(s) Value Input
Echo Example: When Variable Returns 5 Echo Hi
```

---

How am I suppose to prevent it from counting 

***%A137501argument%A137501currentargument%***
 as 
***%A137501argument(argumentnumber)%*** ???

Comment: Could you explain each of the input variables for your script? `Usage: %~n0 varName Return Value Input`

Comment: Without looking any further - `%137501arg%` will not be evaluated to the contents of `"137501arg` but to the contents of `%1` concatenated with the string `37501arg` and the trailing `%` introduces a context-sensitive element into the mix. Simply stated - don't use variables which start with a numeric. The syntax error is very specific - the `if` statement is not formed correctly - probably related to the presence of three `%` on the lhs which makes the `==` appear to be part of the lhs argument and hence no `==` operator is found.

Comment: David, it works like a IF Statement, When varName Return Value it does whatever the input is. Like When Variable Return 5 echo hi